# Fullcalendar duplicates events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I use `fullcalendar.js` in my site. I save parameters in settingsOBJ variable and then create the calendar.

`$('#calendar').fullCalendar(settingsOBJ);` But when I sync with my google calendar I add new events to calendar  like this

```
for(i=0; i < gEvents.length; i++){
                            if(gEvents[i].start['timeZone']){
                                var da_te_start = moment(gEvents[i].start['dateTime']).tz(gEvents[i].start['timeZone']).format();
                                gEvents[i].start.dateTime = da_te_start;
                                var da_te_end = moment(gEvents[i].end['dateTime']).tz(gEvents[i].end['timeZone']).format();
                                gEvents[i].end.dateTime = da_te_end;
                            }

                            (typeof(gEvents[i].colorId)   === 'undefined'? backgroundColor   = colors[0].value : backgroundColor =colors[gEvents[i].colorId].value);
                            fixGoogleDate(gEvents[i].end,gEvents[i].start);

                            (typeof(gEvents[i].description)   === 'undefined'? desc      = "": desc = gEvents[i].description);

                            var eventReady = new Object();

                            eventReady = {

                                backgroundColor:backgroundColor,

                                date:get_date(gEvents[i].start,gEvents[i].end)+timeZone,

                                desc: desc,

                                end: gEvents[i].end.dateTime || gEvents[i].end.date,    

                                id:gEvents[i].id,

                                imageUrl:"",

                                organizer:"",

                                start: gEvents[i].start.dateTime || gEvents[i].start.date, 

                                title: gEvents[i].summary,

                                venue:""

                            };
                            gEventsReady.push(eventReady);

                        }
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', gEventsReady);
```

. Everything works perfect if defaultview of calendar is month, but when defaultview is agenda calendar dublicates the events. And when change the view dublicated events are deleted.Who can help?

Comment: You haven't shown what causes this code to be executed, but I would guess this is because you keep adding more event sources to the calendar without removing any of the ones added earlier.

Comment: Thank you ADyson. I fixed the issue. I delated the old events then added the new ones.